# How can I use individually GZipped images in Sagemaker Batch Transform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to run Batch Transform, but I keep getting http 500 errors in the logs and a failure.

My data is several thousand individually GZipped images.

Using application/x-image as the Content Type results in just a bunch of http status 500 errors in the data-log Cloudwatch output, but leaving it blank results in a "invalid start byte" errors. `ERROR in serving: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte`

Since I can't use a blank content type or x-image, what format can I use to batch transform the individually gzipped files?

Answer (score 0):

If your input is Gzipped, you can set the compression type to "Gzip" per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_TransformInput.html so that SageMaker will decompress your input before sending it to the model container.